# How to implement funcitonality that can be used on different kinds of objects?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have to implement a 'global' search/filter function in my application. Each window that contains a list of information, whether it's a DataGrid or some other implementation of a list has to have a search box, and if the user enters text in the search box, it'll filter that list by whatever's being searched for. I only want to implement the search logic once.

For the most part, this won't necessarily be too difficult. The reason is that most windows that contain a list will be based on the same datatype. These are all ViewModels, and each of these ViewModels extends ViewModelBase, and ViewModelBase contains the data that I'll be searching.

A rudimentary example:

```
public class ZoneVm : ViewModelBase
{
    // Zone specific functionality
}

public class UserVm : ViewModelBase
{
    // User specific functionality
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    // The handy thing about the common view model base is that 
    // I can contain the model binding in a single place

    // It will be easy to search List<ZoneVm> and List<UserVm> because
    // they are both effectively List<ViewModelBase>. 
}
```

The difficulty lies in the outlier objects that I have to search. Some windows contain a list of objects that *don't* extend ViewModelBase, so I won't have this predictable list of properties to search, e.g.

```
public class PanelData // doesn't implement ViewModelBase :-(
{
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    // other properties that I'll have to search/filter on
}
```

Is there a 'best practices' approach to this kind of task? Are there design patterns that solve this problem? How should I approach having to search/filter 2 (and probably more) different kinds of list?

Comment: Have you considered using Reflection? You could mark these kind of properties with an Attribute and parse them when your application loads, and keep a cached list of Accessors to these search/filterable properties.

Comment: Hi @dowhilefor (nice name, btw :-)), I haven't considered reflection but thinking now it might be something that might work. I could iterate over each property (whatever it is) and compare its 'ToString()' value against the search term. I'll keep that in mind as I explore this further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will not want to have each data to have a common searchable member?
(this could be handeled by using a common IData-Interface with this abstract member as Ofer said)

I would have them in a queriable collection and implement the search in an abstract fasion (please fill in the blanks yourself):

```
class MySearchableDataListBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   List<T> _list = new List<T>();
   string _currentFilterString = "";

   abstract bool FilterItemPredicate(T item, string query);

   public abstract IEnumerable<T> FilteredItems
   {
      get {
         return _list.Where(i => FilterItemPredicate(i, _currentFilterString)).ToArray();
      }
   }

   public string FilterQuery
   {
      get { return _currentFilterString; }
      set {
         if (value != _currentFilterString)
         {
             _currentFilterString = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("FilterQuery");
             OnPropertyChanged("FilteredItems");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can then use this as a collection for your data and provide Commands and Properties for the filtering/searching.

Comment: This wasn't *exactly* the answer, but it provided a good framework to get started with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create an interface instead of a base class, i.e. `IViewModelBase`. This interface can be empty. In addition, create your base class but it will be specific for certain objects only (and it would be abstract also).

```
public interface IViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}

public abstract class Vm : IViewModelBase 
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class ZoneVm : Vm
{
    // Zone specific functionality
}

public class UserVm : Vm
{
    // User specific functionality
}

public class PanelData : IViewModelBase
{
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at mixins: [re](http://remix.codeplex.com/)-[mix](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192716/re-mix-A-Mixin-Library-for-NET)

It allows you to mix functionalities in objects (it's a bit like multi-inheritance).
You can then provide interfaces implementations and have, for example, a class that inherits Window AND has the methods/properties of ViewModelBase, available through an interface.